# removing nulls to condense a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table with hundreds of col. From col1 to col150.. Most of the values are null.

I need to be able get rid of all the nulls and condense the table down.
How would I do that?

Here is an example of the table

```
   am_525384-010        NULL    NULL    47.00   50.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
   am_487679-100        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    98.001  98.00   NULL    NULL    NULL        
   am_454251-090        NULL    NULL    50.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
   am_443915-050        NULL    58.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
   am_555440-060        NULL    NULL    50.00   NULL    45.00   NULL    NULL    59.00   NULL    NULL    
   am_354701-412        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
   am_431998-016        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    40.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    
   am_511441-172        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

And this is what I would want it to look like

```
       am_525384-010        47.00   50.00   NULL        
       am_487679-100        98.01   98.00   NULL            
       am_454251-090        50.00   NULL    NULL
       am_443915-050        58.00   NULL    NULL    
       am_555440-060        50.00   45.00   59.00       
       am_354701-412        NULL    NULL    NULL   
       am_431998-016        40.00   NULL    NULL    
       am_511441-172        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

How would I do this in MSSQL?

Comment: What is the exact logic here?

Comment: You better change the schema by unpivoting your table once and for all then you'll never have this problem again.

Comment: pivot may not work there are thousands or rows...

Comment: You should convert this table to Sparxmatrix then use query on sparxmatrix tale.

Comment: SQL Server has [sparse columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) for this type of case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First UNPIVOT

```
Select id, colnam, colval
into unpivoted
From (Select * FROM table) AS t
UNPIVOT (colval for colnam in (col1, col2, ...)) as u
```

This turns your example data into something like this

```
id             colnam colval
am_525384-010  col3   47.00
am_525384-010  col4   50.00
am_487679-100  col6   98.001
am_487679-100  col7   98.00
...
```

Then get the distinct colnams found and use that to generate a select to pivot it back

```
declare @s nvarchar(4000);
set @s = "";
select @s=@s+',['+colnam+']' from (select distinct colnam from unpivoted) x
set @s='select * from unpivoted pivot (sum(colval) for colnam in ('+substring(@s,2,len(@s)-1)+')) as p';
```

which will generate a pivot select to put it back in columns, like this:

```
Select * FROM Unpivoted
PIVOT (SUM(colval) for colnam in ([col2],[col3],[col4],...)) as p
```

Comment: can you please try and explain to me how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make a script that figures out which columns to include in a query and use that to make a string that is a select that can be executed.

```
declare @s nvarchar(4000)
set @s='declare @x nvarchar(4000); select @x=''select id'''
select @s=@s+'+case when count(['+name+'])>0 then '',['+name+']'' else '''' end' from sys.columns where object_id=OBJECT_ID('table') and name like 'col%'
set @s=@s+'+'' from table'' from table; exec sp_executesql @x'
exec sp_executesql @s
```

This makes a string which when executed uses a query to make a string that is a select with just columns that have values.

Comment: what is `all` doing in this..?

Comment: is it same as `count(columnname)`